# Python thread class - exiting threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using thread to invoke a function which runs as :

```
def fillIQ(ipno):
    global inp_width
    global no_exit
    try:
        while 1 :
            if no_exit==1:
                sys.exit()       # <exit line>
            tags=[]
            for i in range(ipno):
                yn=random.randint(0,1)
                if yn==1:
                    voqno=random.randint(0,ipno-1)
                    if inpQ[i][voqno]<10:
                        inpQ[i][voqno]+=1
                    tag="iq"
                    tags.append(tag)
            d.update()
            time.sleep(2)
            d.delete("iq")
            drawIQ(ipno)

    except BaseException ,e:
        print "fillIQ > "+e
```

I am changing the value of no_exit in the main function. But once I change it the thread is not getting exit. Because next time I create a thread for another instance with different inputs( its a GUI program. for one input i execute the thread and later, change input and execute it again) the odler thread appears to run.

Comment: how do you know that it appears to run?

Comment: its a GUI program that emulates packet arrival. First i emulated for 3 input ports. then i changed the input to 4 in the GUI and simulated, but the arrived packet co ordinates appear to be invalid for the new input but matches with the old one.

Comment: `exit` and `sys.exit` only cause the python interpreter to exit if called in the main thread. If you just want a thread to finish then cause the function to finish by using the return statement or throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To exit a thread you must either return from it or raise SystemExit(). Returning actually raises a SystemExit exception in the context of a thread. But you are catching that exception and not re-raising it.

```
>>> isinstance(SystemExit(1), BaseException)
True
```

There's your problem. Either catch SystemExit exceptions separately and re-raise it explicitly, or be more selective with your general catching, or re-raise **everything** you catch. For brevity, I give an example of the former

```
except SystemExit:
    raise
except BaseException:
    print "fillIQ > ", e
```

Also, note that it's `, e` and not `+e` since e is not a string. There were a couple of other issues I encountered just trying to get your thread to run, but I'm sure you'll figure them out quickly enough, mostly missing imports and other values that are not listed in your example.